# Select all paragraphs but first - REGEX

Tags: regex, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I am looking for a regular expression that would select all paragraphs in a text box but the first one. This expression would be used for paragraph styling in Adobe InDesign.

Comment: Best of luck with that. Let us know if you have any specific questions after trying yourself.

Comment: Boy talk about trying to apply a sledgehammer to drive your screws!

Comment: Well I tried the following expression ~7[]\Z but to no avail. ~7 represents the soft return sumbol (first occurence at the end of the first paragraph), the square brackets represent "everything in-between" and \Z represents "end of story".

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^(?<=\r)(.|\r|\n){1,999999999}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Thank you for trying though!

Comment: I wonder how your file is set up because it works at my end on every file I try. It finds all paragraphs starting from second down to the end of flow.

Comment: Are you using InDesign or another regex processor? InDesign regular expressions do not share the exact same syntax as "plain" regex. This webpage http://www.ericagamet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Erica-Gamets-GREP-Cheat-Sheet.pdf lists simple GREP expressions you could compare to "plain" regex. As for my file setup, I created a character style that italicizes text and assigned it to your expression (just as in following link) http://blogs.adobe.com/indesignpost/2010/11/quick-tip-automatic-formatting-using-grep-styles-in-adobe-indesign/

Comment: What about a paragraph style that wouls specify the first paragraph aspect then call for next style defining the 2nd top n paragraphs look ?